# When I close a thread created by a dll plugin, the whole program closes

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I need a thread timer for a plugin. The code executes well. The problem is when closing the plugin must close the created thread.

When the thread closes, the whole program closes. How can I close the safe plugin without closing the whole parent program.

```
class MYCLASS {
public:
.............
    static DWORD WINAPI threadProc(LPVOID innerThread) {
        MYCLASS *pThis = reinterpret_cast<MYCLASS*>(innerThread);
            
            if (pThis->process_on) {
                // EXECUTE         
      }

            Sleep(100);
        }
        exit(0); 
    }
  MYCLASS::OnClose();

.............

private:  
    bool process_on;

    HANDLE hThread; DWORD ThreadID;
  
.............

hThread=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadProc, (void*)this, 0, &ThreadID);
..............


void MYCLASS::OnClose() {
    thread_process=false;   
    DWORD dwExitCode;
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &dwExitCode);
    ExitThread(dwExitCode);
}
```

Comment: `exit(0);` exits the process, not the thread.

Comment: so, and what is the right code?

Comment: If you just return normally from the thread function, it will exit by itself. Or you could use the `ExitThread` function.

Comment: return 0; it's worse, close the program too and more the thread remain on hold (executable stil on task manager)

ExitThread(dwExitCode); already used

Comment: I *think* the `OnClose` function should stop the thread, but I don't see how this is happening here. Also why do you need a thread in the first place?

Comment: I can't write all the code here, but OnClose is called. Stop the thread but also the parent program

Comment: SOLVED, I replaced ExitThread with TerminateThread and working.

Comment: TerminateThread is a [bad idea](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=91811).

Comment: So, what it's your solution ?

Comment: Since I don't fully understand your problem (I don't think you showed all relevant code), I don't have a solution. As I asked before, why do you even need a thread?

Comment: For a VST audio plugin, it is necessary to have my own timer, independent of the host. I repeat, the timer works, only when closing the plugin on the VST host interface the whole program closes (VST host)